# В чем логика вызова отдельной переменной или id view элемента kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть bottomNavigationView, я его объявил так:

```
 val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation_t) as BottomNavigationView
```

дальше у меня есть получается две переменные, которые отвечают за эту вьюху: `navigation_t` и `bottomNavigationView` и я могу вызвать две переменные. В чем логика и какую переменную нужно вызвать?

P.S. пример:

```
navigation_t.inflateMenu(R.menu.---)
```

или

```
bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.---)
```

Comment: любую, очевидно.

Comment: почему любую, получается что я могу не объявлять переменную и просто вызвать по id с разметки, но тогда зачем переменную можно сделать, разве  что для глобал переменных

Comment: В принципе да, но эта строка: val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation_t) as BottomNavigationView, в принципе не имеет смысла, таким образом вы создаёте лишнюю переменную. используйте только: navigation_t.inflateMenu(R.menu.---) или как вариант: (navigation_t as BottomNavigationView).inflateMenu(R.menu.---)

Comment: _я могу не объявлять переменную и просто вызвать по id с разметки, но тогда зачем переменную можно сделать_ - например для доступа к динамическим элементам

Comment: Я частенько встречаю ваши вопросы по Kotlin, посмотрите на книгу: Жемеров, Исакова: Kotlin в действии

Comment: @Valeriy. ну формально тут к котлину мало вопрос относится

Comment: @Grundy, писатели постарались сделать упор на Android и на большинство встреченных вопросов, ответы можно найти в этой книге. Но как говорится: библию каждый трактует по своему. Вот я и написал то, как это понимаю.

Comment: @Valeriy, моих вопросов по котлину намного меньше чем до джаве относительно android программирования, просто иногда сложновато понять то что годами используешь через java в android и его аналог в kotlin :)

Comment: У меня по меньше опыта будет и тоже сразу сложно перейти от одного написания принципа к другому, но самое веселое, когда в течении одного дня приходится прыгать между языками. Читать ещё ничего, а вот писать...

Comment: но тем не менее язк довольно удобный и перейти с java на него не очень то и проблематично :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), то получать ссылку на объект разметки (View) через метод  `findViewById()` нет никакой надобности, так как одна из функций этого плагина - прямой импорт ссылок на объекты разметки для исключения этого метода из кода с целью его упрощения,   как

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`
```

импортирует ссылки на все виджеты разметки *activity_main.xml*

При этом вы можете обратиться к объекту на разметке через его ID в этой разметке, так для виджета с ID `@+id/textView` вы обращаетесь через `textView`, например:

```
textView.setText("Hello")
```

Однако API android это расширение изменить не может и метод `findViewById()` по прежнему работает и выполняет свою функцию, хотя надобность в нем практически отпала.

Использовать надо первый вариант в вашем вопросе (и совсем не использовать получение ссылок через `findViewById()`), если вы подключили плагин KAE или отключить этот плагин и использовать второй, классический, вариант - они взаимозаменяемые, но первый не в пример удобнее.